# Creating ToDoList using Python OOP

Tags: python, oop

So I started to learn about OOP in Python. I've simple task of creating ToDoList. I don't need to save anything in txt file or other format. This is the test code that has to work with my program:

```
mylist = ToDoList('My sample ToDoList')
for i in range(1, 11):
   task = Task(f'Simple task #{i}')
   if i % 2:
       task.finish()
   mylist.add_task(task)
mylist.print_list()
```

And this is the expected output:

```
My sample ToDoList
###
[x] Simple task #1
[ ] Simple task #2
[x] Simple task #3
[ ] Simple task #4
[x] Simple task #5
[ ] Simple task #6
[x] Simple task #7
[ ] Simple task #8
[x] Simple task #9
[ ] Simple task #10
```

For now my code looks like this:

```
class ToDoList(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.n = name
        print(name,"\n","#################")
        self.d = None
    def add_task(self, dic):
        self.d = dic
    def print_list(self):
        for i in self.d:
            if self.d[i] == 'undone':
                print("[ ]" + str(i))
            elif self.d[i] == 'done':
                print("[x]" + str(i))

class Task:
    tasks = {}
    def __init__(self, task):
        self.t = task
        print(task)
        self.tasks[task] = 'undone'

    def finish(self):
        self.tasks[task] = 'done'


mylist = ToDoList('My simple ToDoList')
for i in range(1, 11):
    task = Task(f'Simple task #{i}')
    if i % 2:
        task.finish()
    mylist.add_task(task)
mylist.print_list()
```

And this is the output of my code for now:

```
My simple ToDoList 
 #################
Simple task #1
Simple task #2
Simple task #3
Simple task #4
Simple task #5
Simple task #6
Simple task #7
Simple task #8
Simple task #9
Simple task #10
```

Right now I'm stuck. I have a part where I create my dictionary of undone tasks and then I change the values to done. I want to pass this dictionary to my ToDoList class and just print the keys and values. I feel like the solution is really simple, but I can't seem to find it. I'll gladly take any advice about code optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is a great language for object oriented programming, but it also has many high level language features that make some user defined classes unnecessary.  For example, your `ToDoList` doesn't (currently) add more than what a Python `list` provides.  Not to say that you might not need such a class in the future, but when that time comes you will probably want to add list-like special methods to allow it to behave like a real `list` and support iteration, for example.

So, for a stripped down solution, I focused on your `Task` class which is essential, but doesn't necessarily need to mimic a dictionary.  As a next step you can start adding attributes and methods to it to support features like description text, due dates, etc.

Note: It is almost always a good idea to leave output methods like `print` out of your classes.  If you want your classes to be reusable then you will find that different clients have different output requirements - let the client, not the class worry about the output side of things.

Example:

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.done = False

task_list = []
for id in range(1, 11):
    task = Task(f"Simple task #{id}")
    if id % 2 == 0:
        task.done = True
    task_list.append(task)
         
for task in task_list:
    print(f"[{'X' if task.done else ' '}] {task.name}")
```

Output:

```
[ ] Simple task #1
[X] Simple task #2
[ ] Simple task #3
[X] Simple task #4
[ ] Simple task #5
[X] Simple task #6
[ ] Simple task #7
[X] Simple task #8
[ ] Simple task #9
[X] Simple task #10
```

Comment: Thanks! Your example really helped me to wrap my head around it.